# how to import one project(.zexp file) to another project?

Tags: zope

can any one tell how to solve

```
TypeError:('object.__new__(X): X is not a type object (classobj)', <function
_reconstructor at 0xb766fa04>, (<class DateTime.DateTime.DateTime at 0x9382d4c>, <type 
'object'>, None))
```

while importing a one project(for ex. brundelre3.zexp file) to another in zmi.

I tried it importing the project(brundelre3.zexp) already in zmi under / ->import/export (tab)-> import file name ->ownership-> selected the radio button of Retain existing ownership information-> import (button) so it worked properly before but its not working now . Can anyone tell whats the reason for my error.

Answer (score 0):

I can only make wild guesses, you probably need to debug it:

Perhaps you have created a type that has a name that clashes with something built-in.